# Dynamically change log target file using Enterprise Logging

Tags: c#, logging, app-config, enterprise-library

So I'm trying to use `enterprise logging` in an application, and I want it to have multiple files, so far I have the following in my `app.config file`:

```
<add name="Normal" fileName="C:\MyApp\Logs.log" .../>
```

And in my code I'm simply using

```
Logging.Write("My log here");
```

Now what if I want to programatically change the file where it's being logged to `C:\MyApp\MyDateHere_Logs.log`, how could I approach this?

Haven't found a lot of solutions online. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Are you logging to different files for specific reasons? If you want you can create categories and stamp that on each of your log writes. And within the configuration file you can have different listeners go to different file locations depending on the Category Type.

Comment: This way the logging can still be config driven and you don't have to change code to change the location of the files.  However if you really want to change it in program you'll have use the configuration manager to get your exe's config and navigate down to the logging configuration then get the flat file trace listener object modify the file name and save.

Comment: I don't have a specific hard-coded reason for this as this will change very frequently, so I'll try using the configuration manager and keep modifying the flat file trace listener, I'll keep this updated, thanks!

Comment: When do you want to change the file name?  Is it every day?  Or just when the web.config changes?  What version of EntLib are you using?

Comment: Hey Tuzo, I have just posted my own answer, for anyone wondering I'm using Entity Framework 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I ended up creating a custom trace listener of my own and then changing the filename attribute on runtime by following the guide [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650498.aspx).

You can access the attribute which stores your path by using `Attribute["filename"]` (assuming the attribute in your config file's trace listener node has the path in an attribute named "filename".)